# Estilo de fonte diferente em cada navegador

Tags: html, css

Criei um site e fui testar nos navegadores, e notei que em cada navegador a fonte utilizada fica de um jeito.

[image: foto01]

Coloquei até uma foto para vocês verem como fica, a dúvida é:

- **É possível colocar a fonte do chrome, para ser padrão em qualquer navegador?**

Comment: Qual o seu CSS para essa palavra?

Comment: bom, coloquei font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif; na body, pra pegar no site inteiro... e na palavra, coloquei apenas isso: 
 width: 185px;
 font-size: 2.1em;
 color: #DCBB4D;
 margin: auto;

Comment: com o que vc me passou aqui deu igual  https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4pVD.png

Comment: engraçado que seu exemplo ficou igual em todos os navegadores... será que é porque estou usando fonte do google font?

Comment: posso experimentar, passa ela pra mim

Comment: html: <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
 css: font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;

Comment: https://fonts.google.com/?query=quick&selection.family=Quicksand

Comment: Parece que por algum motivo sua fonte no FF está ficando com BOLD. Tente colocar um `font-weight:normal !important` ou `font-weight:400 !important` direto na tag do seu texto para testar.

Comment: Opa, coloquei na pagina e tem links para mais duas opções, confere http://kithomepage.com/sos/fonte.html

Answer (score 0):

Aplique o mesmo font-weight em ambas as fontes. Às vezes a fonte renderizada abre de maneiras diferentes conforme você aplica em um markup que já possui bold por padrão, como um h1, h2, etc.

Certifique-se também de que sua fonte não foi simplesmente convertida por um serviço como o Font Squirrel, pois ela pode perder configurações durante a transformação para webfont.